# Understand making a grid ( Eloquent js chapter 6)

Tags: javascript

There is a part in chapter 6 of eloquent js, where they introduce laying out a table, after talking about prototypes and constructors ( For more details you can see http://eloquentjavascript.net/06_object.html). The full code for what I am asking for is here (https://jsfiddle.net/n3uzssq1/). However They present the code in blocks, so I would like to first ask a question about the first piece they give and analyze namely:

```
function rowHeights(rows) {
  return rows.map(function(row) {
    return row.reduce(function(max, cell) {
      return Math.max(max, cell.minHeight());
    }, 0);
  });
}

function colWidths(rows) {
  return rows[0].map(function(_, i) {
    return rows.reduce(function(max, row) {
      return Math.max(max, row[i].minWidth());
    }, 0);
  });
}
```

In the book and in the full code as I gave the link for the description for the following functions are given as

**1.**`minHeight()` returns a number indicating the minimum height this cell requires (in lines).

**2.** `minWidth()` returns a number indicating this cell’s minimum width (in characters).

**3.** `draw(width, height)` returns an array of length height, which contains a series of strings that are each width characters wide. This represents the content of the cell.

Now I'm having trouble starting to analyze this code.

**First**: What is `rowHeights` trying to do? From the `.reduce` part it makes me think we are summing all heights of the rows, but then why do we do `Math.max`? Math.max returns either `max` or `cell.minHeight` depending on whats bigger, so why are we doing this? Also how is `.map` working here? I have used `.map` before to map one array to another by doing `arrayTwo = array.map...`, so what is that even doing, its not like we are mapping one array to another. We are returning rows.map, how does that make sense? I have some more questions but I think if I understand these I will be able to proceed farther. I'm having a hard time understand what the book is trying to even do, as its a bit unclear to me as to what we are trying to achieve.

Comment: this is going to be a long one to answer, not that its a bad question. I suggest you throw in some console.log statements in there and see whats getting done to what.

Comment: This book is so frustrating. They generally start with really easy examples with pretty good explanations, and then do much more complex ( for me atleast) lines of code, with the same amount of explanation.

Comment: Hopefully one of the answers help you out, but IMO this is one of those things you have to struggle through yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What these two functions are doing is returning arrays of heights for rows and widths for columns.

The [map<sup><sub>*MDN*</sub></sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) will iterate the set of rows/columns and for each row/column it will take the result of reduce. [Reduce<sup><sub>*MDN*</sub></sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) is an accumulator, it can be used to sum, but here it is being used to check the largest value present (hence the Math.max check).

The overall result is an array of rows with each value being the max height of each row, and an array of columns with each value being the max width of each column.

Here is an example of max being used in reduce to show it taking the maximum value of an array.

```js
var numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];

var maxNumber = numbers.reduce(function(prev,cur){ 
    return Math.max(prev,cur);
},0);//0 being the default value that is assigned to prev in the first iteration

console.log(maxNumber);//8
```

Comment: Why do we want the array of heights for rows and width for columns. How does that help us, in whatever we are trying to achieve?

Comment: @cresjoy - Well, if you knew the largest height of a cell in a row, you could set that entire row to that height to even out the cells. If you knew the max width in a column, you could set that entire column to that width to even out the cells. And if you knew both the max height of each row and each column you could easily determine the size that the resultant table would occupy.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. What are we trying to do? What does a "cell" imply? To my understanding a grid is something like  https://jsfiddle.net/2ghnh618/                                                      This has four columns, and two rows. And 8 cells. What does it mean "max-height" of a row? Or max width of a column?

Comment: @cresjoy - A row is generally referred to as a single line of entry. In the example you link to, from the relevant section, a row of data would be `Kilimanjaro    5895 Tanzania`. In contrast, a column tends to refer to a particular field and its associated values. In the example you link to, same section, a column of data would be `country Tanzania Nepal Japan Italy/France Netherlands United States Mexico`.

Comment: @cresjoy - Also keep in mind, the reason that this needs to be defined is simply the way the table is being drawn, it is using exact sizing to make an in text table. From your link: "*The way our table-building system will work is that the builder function will ask each cell how wide and high it wants to be and then use this information to determine the width of the columns and the height of the rows. The builder function will then ask the cells to draw themselves at the correct size and assemble the results into a single string.*"

Comment: I see. Could you explain more on the usage of map here? I still dont quite get it. From my understand map literally maps something to another array and does something depending on what we specify from the original array to the new one. It doesent seem to do that here